# Basic Vector3 Movement disrupted if player looks at mouse position C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to rewrite an old game I worked on a month back but I am having trouble implementing my movement scripts.

As of now, I have a basic movement system where I just add speed and force relating to L,R,U,D arrow keys. I am doing this instead of getting basic horizontal and vertical axis because they had problems with my next bit of code.

Everything is alright until I add in My script where the player looks at the `mousePosition`. I am guessing when my player rotates towards my mouse position, its idea of which is left and which is right gets jumbled up.

Here is the code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class movement : MonoBehaviour {
    private Camera mainCamera;
    public float speed = 5f;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () 
    {
        mainCamera = FindObjectOfType<Camera>();
    }

    void LookAtPositionOfMouse()
    {
        Ray cameraRay = mainCamera.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
        Plane groundPlane = new Plane(Vector3.up, Vector3.zero);
        float raylength;

        if (groundPlane.Raycast(cameraRay, out raylength))
        {
            Vector3 pointToLook = cameraRay.GetPoint(raylength);
            Debug.DrawLine(cameraRay.origin, pointToLook, Color.blue);
            transform.LookAt(new Vector3(pointToLook.x, transform.position.y, pointToLook.z));
        }
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.RightArrow))
        {
            transform.position += Vector3.right * speed * Time.deltaTime;
        }

        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftArrow))
        {
            transform.position += Vector3.left * speed * Time.deltaTime;
        }

        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.UpArrow))
        {
            transform.position += Vector3.forward * speed * Time.deltaTime;
        }

        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.DownArrow))
        {
            transform.position += Vector3.back * speed * Time.deltaTime;
        }

        LookAtPositionOfMouse();
    }
}
```

I know this is a very primitive way of doing this, but I would like to keep everything simple for now as I try and figure this out.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The thing is that when you alter the position of your transform you are not taking it's rotation into account.

You should probably be fine just multiplying the current `transform.rotation`.

```
transform.position += transform.rotation * Vector3.forward * speed * Time.deltaTime;
```